# Vuex: Two-Way binding / reactivity not working

Tags: vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js, vue-reactivity

I've a problem with reactivity when I update my form.
I'm doing an copy of the Object in the Store, change the Values in the Copy and after this I want to write the result back into the state in the Store.

Writing the changed Values in the Backend is working. But for some reason the Values on the Website are not updating.

Did anyone have an idea how to solve the Problem?
Thanks in advance :-)

**component:**

```
 <template>
      <div>
        <label for="hiveId">Volk ID</label>
        <b-form-input
          id="hiveId"
          v-model="lSelectedHive._id"
          value="lSelectedHive._id"
          readonly
        />
        <label for="hiveName">Volk Name</label>
        <b-form-input
          id="hiveName"
          v-model="lSelectedHive.name"
        ></b-form-input>
        <label for="hiveNumber">Volk Nummer</label>
        <b-form-input id="hiveNumber" v-model="lSelectedHive.number"></b-form-input>
        <label for="hiveComment">Kommentar</label>
        <b-form-input
          id="hiveComment"
          v-model="lSelectedHive.comment"
        ></b-form-input>
        <label for="hiveBuildType">Kommentar</label>
        <b-form-select id="hiveBuildType" v-model="lSelectedHive.buildType">
          <option v-for="bt in buildTypes" :key="bt" :value="bt">{{ bt }}</option>
        </b-form-select>
        <label for="hiveStatus">Status</label>
        <b-form-select id="hiveStatus" v-model="lSelectedHive.status">
          <option v-for="hs in hiveStatuses" :key="hs" :value="hs">{{ hs }}</option>
        </b-form-select>
        <b-button @click="updateSelectedHive(lSelectedHive)">Click me</b-button>
    
        {{ lSelectedHive.name }}
      </div>
    </template>
    
    <script>
    import { mapState, mapActions } from 'vuex'
    export default {
      computed: {
        ...mapState({
          selectedHive: (state) => state.hives.selectedHive,
          buildTypes: (state) => state.bmConfig.buildTypes,
          hiveStatuses: (state) => state.bmConfig.hiveStatuses
        }),
    
        lSelectedHive() {
          return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.selectedHive))
        }
      },
  methods: {
    ...mapActions('hives', ['updateSelectedHive']),
    }
  }
    }
```

**Action:**

```
async updateSelectedHive({ commit }, hive) {
await this.$axios
  .put(this.$axios.defaults.baseURL + '/api/v1/hives/' + hive._id, hive)
  .then((res) => {
    if (res.status === 200) {
      commit('setHive', res.data.data)
    }
  })
},
```

**Mutation:**

```
  setHive(state, hive) {
    state.selectedHive = hive
```

Comment: First think is to clean up your action. You're using "await" with ".then" chaining. Use one or the other. And in this case, you'd want res.data, not res.data.data.

Comment: I've used res.data.data because res.data contains an data-Object ;-) Your comment with the chaining is correct, but that don't solve the problem with the reactivity ;-)

Comment: Have you tried with ...mapState('moduleName', ['stateProp1', 'stateProp2']), in computed?

Comment: Oh, is your property nested in an object? If so, it won't have reactivity.

Comment: I found the issue. The problem was not the Property, it was the component which is displaying the result.